# Removing preview DNS from Google Index

Tags: google-index

I just discovered that Google have indexed the preview version of my site with a subdomain `previewdns.com` appended to my actual domain. I need to remove those URL's from the search index. How can I do so?

Comment: If the subdomain isn't there any more, won't they just vanish?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the [Google public URL removal tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals).
2. Click **New removal request**.
3. Type the URL of the webpage that's been changed (not the Google search results URL or cached page URL). The URL is case-sensitive—use exactly the same characters and capitalization that the site uses. [How to find the right URL](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=63758).
4. Click **Continue**.
5. Type a word that appears on the out-of-date cached version of the page, but not anywhere on the live version. This is to help Google understand that the page has changed.
6. It’s often more effective to type a single word rather than a phrase. Don’t describe the removed content or the changes made; instead, explicitly provide a word that was in the old version but is missing from the new. For example, the cached page might contain your name, which has since been removed from the live version. In this case, don’t tell us that "my name has been removed'; instead, type your actual name ("Sylvia") as it appears in the cached version.
7. Click **Remove cache**.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great case for using the [canonical meta link tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html).  Putting a tag like:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish" />
```

into each of your pages will tell Googlebot which URL is the correct URL of your site.  Even if Googlebot finds a page at a non-standard URL (such as previewdns), then it will only index it at the canonical URL.